# The Hamiltonian of a rigid diatomic molecule

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism

The kinetic energy of a rigid diatomic molecule consisting of two point atoms of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ free to rote about its CM is given by $$T=\frac{1}{2\mu r^2}\left(p_\theta^2+\frac{p_\phi^2}{\sin^2\theta}\right)$$ where $\mu=m_1m_2/(m_1+m_2)$, and $r$ is the distance between them. I want to show that the quantity inside the parenthesis is the square of the angular momentum $L^2$. I start with $$\vec{L}=\vec{r}\times\vec{p}=r\hat{r}\times(p_\theta\hat{\theta}+p_\phi\hat{\phi})=rp_\theta\hat{\phi}-rp_\phi\hat{\theta}$$ so that $$L^2=\vec{L}\cdot\vec{L}=r^2p_\theta^2+r^2p_\phi^2.$$ But this is clearly wrong on dimensional grounds. But I don't understand how to go about it then.

Comment: I think you are confusing the notation. $p_i=(0,p_{\theta},p_{\phi})=(0,\mu r^2\dot{\theta},\mu r^2\dot{\phi})$. Compare the expression with the one given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_rotor)

Comment: Yes, I have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$L=\vec{r}\times \mu\dot{\vec{r}}=\mu{\vec r}\times (\dot{r}\hat{r}
+r\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}+r\dot{\phi}\sin\theta\hat{\phi)}
=\mu r^2\dot{\theta}\hat{\phi}
-\mu r^2\dot{\phi}\sin\theta\hat{\theta}$$ or
$$L^2=(\mu r^2\dot{\theta})^2+(\mu r^2\dot{\phi}\sin\theta)^2
=p_\theta^2+\frac{p_\phi^2}{\sin^2\theta}$$